# BigInt rounds a number

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bigint

I have few number which I want to convert into string or BigInt because I want to send that number into smart contract but it automatically rounds the number

```
a = 10000000000000000000010; 
convertIntoStringWithoutChangingNumber(a) //'10000000000000000000010' => this should be string

sample inputs and outputs :
10000000000000000000020 // '10000000000000000000020'
10000000000000000001900 // '10000000000000000001900'
10100000000000000000000 // '10100000000000000000000'
```

I have tried few function but it all rounds off the last numeric value to 0. Simply need any way to convert this number into string without altering any digits.

Comment: The number has to start as a BigInt if that's what you want. Your variable `a` is initialized with a plain number, so it's too late to do anything about it after that; the value is already truncated.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what `convertIntoStringWithoutChangingNumber` does?

Comment: Alternatively you can manage your values as strings until you need them as big integers, and convert with `BigInt()`.

Comment: That's not a BigInt but a plain number. Try `a =  10000000000000000000010n;`

Comment: i just want to make function or find any way which can convert this number into string without changing any digits. Also managing with string gives result in e+22 and converting it into string rounds it off as well. simply give me a solution to convert this number into string as it is without rounding off.

Comment: @NiravGhodadra Saying "simply give me a solution to convert " sounds like you're not listening to what the comments are telling you. It's already been explained that your value of `a` is being truncated when it's initialized, there's no way to get it back. You must [initialize it as a BigINt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format to understand what JavaScript numbers can or cannot do. Read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf ("What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic") if you want to learn more.